# Data Report or Crystal Report? Which is which?

Tags: vb.net, report, crystal-reports-2008

Which do you prefer to use, the Data Report or the Crystal Report? I was very confused on what's their difference except that VB 6 uses Data Reports and VB.NET uses Crystal Reports. I do not know what to use.

If you prefer Crystal Reports, may I ask for some resources for beginners. Same with Data Reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the built-in rather than crystal reports.
Both have opposing pros and cons.
Crystal reports is a tad tougher to design but very good to code, I mean send parameters to.
The opposite holds true for the built-in.

Here is a site on Crystal that you may find useful
http://vb.net-informations.com/crystal-report/vb.net_crystal_reports_tutorials.htm